# Debug Keras tensorflow with Visual Studio code

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, keras

I am trying to debug the following dummy code with Visual Studio code. However, even if I use
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True), I always get the autograph_generated file instead of my original python code for the "layer_dummy" method. This seems to be triggered by the Keras input layer. Do you know why and how to fix it?

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

class layer_dummy(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(layer_dummy, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        c_init = tf.ones_initializer()
        self.c = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=c_init(shape=[1,10]),
            trainable=True,
            name="dummy_var",
        )

    def call(self, x):
        return self.c + x


def make_dummy_model():
    vin = tf.keras.Input(shape=([1, 10]))
    ldummy = layer_dummy()
    vout = ldummy(vin)
    dummy_model = Model(inputs=vin, outputs=vout)
    return dummy_model


dummy = make_dummy_model()
dummy.summary()

exit()
```